# What is the purpose of return statement with (**)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, keyword-argument

I am reading about Django [serialization](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/)

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    title = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)
    code = serializers.CharField(style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    linenos = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    language = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python')
    style = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return Snippet.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Why do we need ** in return statement?

Comment: This has nothing to do with return, this is passing the validated_data dict to the `create()` method as keyword args.

Comment: It is not in return statement but in function call statement.

Comment: you need to understand *args and **kwargs in python (Read: https://learnbatta.com/blog/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python-3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use keyword parameter as an argument you need to specify using `**`